# Cygwin equivalent of Linux /dev/sda, /dev/sdb etc

Tags: cygwin, pythonpath, uidevice, block-device, device-management

On Linux, I can access a hard drive as /dev/sdX. This ignores any partition tables, file systems, etc, and just accesses the drive block by block. What is the equivalent in Cygwin? I already searched Google, but could not find anything that works.

I'd like to be able to (for example) create an image of a flash drive with something like

```
dd if=/dev/??? of=image.bin
```

I understand that there are Windows programs to read and write hard drive images. The dd command is just a clarifying example. I am not after creating a drive image. I am after device name.

Answer (score 23):

**In Cygwin** simply **copy-and-past** the following,"**as one long entry**" then **press enter**

```
for F in /dev/s* ; do echo "$F    $(cygpath -w $F)" ; done
```

This should be able to be ran as a script by adding the shebang to the beginning of a  file along with the text from above

Your output should be similar to the following

```
PB-2@PB-2 ~
$ for F in /dev/s* ; do echo "$F    $(cygpath -w $F)" ; done
/dev/scd0    \\.\E:
/dev/scd1    \\.\F:
/dev/sda    \\.\Disk{dc9927e0-d232-e04c-2c75-77f787df605d}
/dev/sda1    \\.\Volume{1200e263-fc48-458c-a1d6-115b385b372c}
/dev/sda2    \\.\HarddiskVolume2
/dev/sda3    \\.\STORAGE#Volume#{7c54accc-b533-11e6-9cce-806e6f6e6963}#0000000025900000#{7f108a28-9833-4b3b-b780-2c6b5fa5c062}
/dev/sda4    \\.\C:
/dev/sda5    \\.\Volume{c3553ab1-e8a5-4d7b-a324-544b32fe3d3e}
/dev/sdb    \\.\Disk{ff7e8c9f-7aa2-1f15-8d02-d126ff13dfb5}
/dev/sdb1    \\.\D:
/dev/sdc    \\.\Disk{07352cef-974b-9296-720f-70f1ae015a85}
/dev/sdc1    \\.\G:
/dev/shm    C:\cygwin64\dev\shm
/dev/sr0    \\.\E:
/dev/sr1    \\.\F:
/dev/stderr    /dev/pty0
/dev/stdin    /dev/pty0
/dev/stdout    /proc/3888/fd/pipe:[94489288360]

PB-2@PB-2 ~
$
```

It took me hours of searching to find this So I'm glad to be sharing it.

If one then wants to know the corresponding Cygpaths

simply type

```
mount
```

And the output should be similar to what follows

```
PB-2@PB-2 ~
$ mount
C:/cygwin64/bin on /usr/bin type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/cygwin64/lib on /usr/lib type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/cygwin64 on / type ntfs (binary,auto)
C: on /cygdrive/c type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
D: on /cygdrive/d type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
E: on /cygdrive/e type udf (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
F: on /cygdrive/f type iso9660 (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
G: on /cygdrive/g type exfat (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)

PB-2@PB-2 ~
$
```

Comment: A bit inelegant but at least it works, unlike the other answer.

Comment: sd* is better than s*

Answer (score 12):

make

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

and you will see the actual mapping of /dev/sdX to their Windows counterparts.

Comment: Mine doesn't. Could you paste your output? It shows `major minor  #blocks  name`, none of which is the windows disk name.

Comment: Can confirm that if a HDD is mounted, this shows the drive letter it's mounted on, under a `win-mounts` header after `name`, and this has been the case for as long as I can remember.

Comment: Curiously, coming back to this, this no longer works for some unknown reason - that is, there's nothing showing in the `win-mounts` column. Can anyone else confirm whether it works on their system?